# CURL Grabs HTML and Parses All Variables into an Array but One - Why?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, curl

Here is the code I am using - I set it up as an example.  As you can see it gets all the variables correctly and sets up the array but the listPrice2 variable is missing...  Please help.

```
     <?php

    $html = "http://www.toysrus.com/family/index.jsp?searchSort=TRUE&categoryId=13131514&s=A-StorePrice&ppg=8";

    $agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$html);
    $html=curl_exec ($ch); 

    function tru_extract( $html , $fields='prodloop-thumbnail=<a href.*\"(.*)\",swatchProdImg=<.*src.*\"(.*)\",prodtitle,adjusted ourPrice2,listPrice2' )
    {

        $arr_data = array();
        if(!$html)
            die("NO Html");

        preg_match_all('@<div class="prodloop_cont.*>(.*)</div.*prodloop_float@isU', $html, $records);
        $arr_get_class = explode(",", $fields );
foreach($records[0] as $r)
    {

        $data = array();
        foreach($arr_get_class as $class)
        {

            $regex = $fieldname ='';
            $regex='class="'.$class.'[\s]*".*>(.*)</';
            $fieldname=$class;
            if(stristr($class, "*"))
            {
                list($fieldname, $regex) = explode("=", $class);
            }
            preg_match('@'.$regex.'@isU', $r, $row);
            $value = trim(strip_tags($row[1]));
            $data[$fieldname] = $value;
        }
        $arr_data[] = $data;

    }

 return $arr_data;

}


$arr_data = tru_extract( $html );
?><pre>
<?php
print_r ($arr_data);
exit;
?>
</pre>
    ?>
```

I have tried adding the full span class and still nothing.  The print_r returns an array of the the variables with the exception of listPrice2.

Comment: i'd suggest use `DOMDocument` + `DOMXpath` for this task, whats the end goal anyway? getting the item name and price and put them inside an array?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.